# NSString is null when converted from a NSURL

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, nsurl

I am using the Open Weather API to get live weather depending on the users location. I first make a variable called `urllink` and set it equal to the http request:

```
NSString *urllink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%f&lon=%f&appid=%@", lat, lng, WEATHERAPIKEY];
```

Then I convert that string to a url. Convert url back to string because I need to change it to `NSData` object:

```
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self urlEncodeValue:urllink]];
NSString *jsonDataString  = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL]; // error on this line
NSLog(@"This is jsonDataString:%@", jsonDataString);
NSData *jsonData = [jsonDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The `urllink` variable converts perfectly to `NSURL`. But when I try to convert the `NSURL` to `NSString` I get `nil`. Which in return gives me `nil` for `NSData`.

So why is the line:

```
 NSString *jsonDataString  = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
```

giving me `nil` for `jsonDataString`?

Comment: did you paste that url to your browser and tested ? What was the result ?

Comment: Yes I did. It gave me the correct json string. So everything worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the scheme (the `https://` or `http://`) in your URL. Thus the request will fail. Furthermore, you should just use `URLWithString` directly:

```
NSString *urllink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%f&lon=%f&appid=%@", lat, lng, WEATHERAPIKEY];

NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urllink];
```

The problem is that you're using `initWithContentsOfURL`, which is (a) synchronous; and (b) doesn't report errors.

You should use `NSURLSession` which is asynchronous and reports errors:

```
NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:jsonURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (data == nil || error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSError *parseError;
    NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
    if (responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", responseObject);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"parseError: %@", parseError);
        NSLog(@"responseString: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: Thank you the error is posted. Something is wrong with my url and it must be the http:, on their website they dont use the http; and it works don't know why. But thank you.

Comment: Yeah, the `http://` is assumed. In fact, if you look at their links in their examples, they show you it without this scheme included, but if you look at the link, itself, it includes `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need an async, data may not yet be present

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // The code runs in background

    do Some Long Operation

});
```

Comment: I have never used an async. Can you show an example how to use it? Also this is happening in viewDidLoad just for your info.

Comment: A call to `initWithContentsOfURL:` with an external URL makes a synchronous network request, which means it will block until completion. So that's not the issue. Although @Harsh.C, synchronous network requests, such as using this method, should generally be avoided.

Comment: Whats another option than. Thats the only way I can think of from getting nsurl to nsdata.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Long running tasks should be handled in background queue and ui related tasks should be in main queue

Comment: @Harsh.C: You never heard of NSURLConnection and NSURLSession ?